# How to select option from api response REACT-JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have Component for select and I want when the response is back the `SelectM` have the selected data and show that

```
import Select from "react-select";

<Select
    menuPlacement="auto"
    menuPosition="fixed"
    styles={colourStyles}
    closeMenuOnSelect={false}
    components={animatedComponents}
    isMulti
    options={colourOptions}
    onChange={handleChangeSelect}
    placeholder="color"
/>
```

this is the options

```
const colourOptions = [
    { value: 'red', label: 'red' },
    { value: 'blue', label: 'blue' },
    { value: 'green', label: 'green' },
];
```

this is handleChangeSelect

```
const handleChangeSelect = (e) => {
    setSelectedValue(Array.isArray(e) ? e.map((x) => x.value) : []);
};
```

this is my response data

```
ResData= [1,2]
```

I want to select from `ResData`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can use [`setValue`](https://react-select.com/props) method of `react-select`.

```
setValue([{value: 'optionA', label:'Option A'}]);
```

In your case it would be something like:

```
const responseData= [1,2];
const colourOptions = [
    { value: 'red', label: 'red' },
    { value: 'blue', label: 'blue' },
    { value: 'green', label: 'green' },
];
const optionsToSelect = colourOptions.filter((option, i) => responseData.includes(i));

...

setValue(optionsToSelect);
```